# One template for 2 thing MeteorJS

Tags: meteor

I have db with `posts` and all of them have bollean `flagged`

I have one template and navigation like (Read, Dont Read).

Problem is that I see all posts (when I must see posts with flagged false or flagged true), and I dont understand why, I think problem in publish/subscribe

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
});

AllPostsController = RouteController.extend({
    template: 'timeTable',
    waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe('allPosts');
    }
});

readPostController = AllPostsController.extend({
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('readPosts');
  }
});

dontreaderPostController = AllPostsController.extend({
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('dontreadPosts');
  }
});


Router.map(function() {
  this.route('timeTable', {path: '/',
        controller: AllPostsController
    });

  this.route('readPosts', {path: '/read',
        controller: readPostsController
    });

  this.route('dontreaderPosts', {
      path: '/dontreader',
      controller: dontreaderPostController
  });
});

Meteor.publish('allPosts', function(){
    return Posts.find({},{ sort: { createdAt: -1 }});
});
Meteor.publish('readPosts', function(){
    return Posts.find({read:true},{ sort: { createdAt: -1 }});
});
Meteor.publish('dontreadPosts', function(){
    return Posts.find({read:false},{ sort: { createdAt: -1 }});
});
```

If someone need more code, Just ask me

Anybody help

**EDIT :** David solved problem for regular tasks. Main problem that I have specific `return Posts.find(...)` in my tamplate helper.

```
<template name="timeTable">
        {{#if posts_exist_week}}
          {{> table posts=week}}
        {{/if}}
        {{#if posts_exist_month}}
          {{> table posts=month}}
        {{/if}}
</template>
<template name="table">
          <table class="main-table table">
              {{#each posts}}
                {{> post}}
              {{/each}}
          </table>
</template>
```

You solved my problem **if I did not have** template `timeTable` (that show posts for last week and month) Because here it **Template helper**

```
Template.timeTable.helpers({
  week: function() {
    //...
    return Posts.find({createdAt: {$gte: weekstart, $lt: yesterday}},{ sort: { createdAt: -1 }}); //return posts that was created in this week
  },
  month: function() {
    //...
    return Posts.find({createdAt: {$gte: monthstart, $lte: weekstart}},{ sort: { createdAt: -1 }}); 
  }
});
```

And now you see that if I choose your decision (David) I will have **2** !!
return

first - in router
second - in template helper

Comment: Always be specific in your question about failures - that helps us narrow our search. By "doesn't work" what do you mean? The template doesn't show? There is no data? You see an error?

Comment: in dontreadposts i see all posts, when I must see only posts with flagged:false

Comment: Did you `meteor remove autopublish`? Did you subscribe anywhere outside of your routes? Either way, this is a good example of when to use the `data` hook, or just a helper inside of you template to restrict the current context.

Comment: 1) Yes 2) No 3) All I try to do is (for example) like when you have in navigation "New Post" and "Best post" they both use one template, but shows different `posts`, I try to built it

Comment: You need your `publish` code in `/server`. In your router you need to have `subscribe` code on a specific route, in a controller, or in `Router.configure({})`. Server publishes, client subscribes.

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny I have this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated this locally and found that `extend` causes the parent controller's `waitOn` to run. So whenever you go to the `/read` route it will actually activate **both** subscriptions and you'll end up with all of the documents on your client. A simple fix is to refactor your controllers like so:

```js
PostController = RouteController.extend({
  template: 'timeTable'
});

AllPostsController = PostController.extend({
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('allPosts');
  }
});

readPostController = PostController.extend({
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('readPosts');
  }
});

dontreaderPostController = PostController.extend({
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('dontreadPosts');
  }
});
```

That being said, you don't want to build your app in a way that it breaks when extra subscriptions happen to be running. I would rewrite the controllers to select only the documents that pertain to them. For example:

```js
dontreaderPostController = PostController.extend({
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('dontreadPosts');
  },
  data: {selector: {read: false}}
});
```

And now your helpers can use the `selector` like this:

```js
Template.timeTable.helpers({
  week: function() {
    var selector = _.clone(this.selector || {});
    selector.createdAt = {$gte: weekstart, $lt: yesterday};
    return Posts.find(selector, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
  }
});
```

Also note that sorting in the publish functions may not be useful - see [common mistakes](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes).

Comment: it's good but my problem is that it's more diffucult than I say because I have more code, I add it to EDIT in post ok?

Comment: I'd recommend making a [meteor pad](http://meteorpad.com/) and sharing the link __or__ linking to a public repository of the code. If you read and understood my answer (especially the first part) and you still need more help, I'll need a complete working version to examine. It seems like my answer really gets at the heart of the issue though - please read it very carefully before asking for more help.

Comment: Great, that right, but I dont know how guys without experience come to this